# How to access the model instance from custom flask admin template

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I need to create a pretty complicated view of nested models in my admin page, googled all around the globe (form_edit_rules, edit_template, on_form_prefill), but could not find a way to access the current DB object from the flask-admin edit page.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current DB object is passed as the variable `model`. See [flask_admin/model/base.py](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py) ~ line 2077:

```
@expose('/edit/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def edit_view(self):

    # code

    model = self.get_one(id)

    # more code

    return self.render(template,
                           model=model,
                           form=form,
                           form_opts=form_opts,
                           return_url=return_url)
```