# Flask Admin Get Instance of Model in ModelView Custom Template

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm currently trying to create a custom ModelView for a detail_view using a template on Flask Admin. However I'm struggling to figure out how to access the instance of a model that the user is viewing the details of.

This is my custom ModelView:

```
class ShopModelView(MyModelView):
    can_view_details = True

    details_template = "custom_detail_view.html"

    @expose('/details/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def details_view(self):
         self._template_args['all_transactions'] = #current_shop_object#.transactions.order_by(Transaction.timestamp.desc())

         return super(ShopModelView, self).details_view()
```

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156201/how-to-access-the-model-instance-from-custom-flask-admin-template), the class of the model can be obtained using `self.model`, however this returns the class rather than the instance of the specific model being accessed.

The documentation on [Templates](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#working-with-the-built-in-templates) and [ModelView](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/?highlight=detail_view) doesn't seem to explain it.

How can I get the instance of the specific model being accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the current instance of the model can be accessed via the variable `model` inside the jinja2 template file. So instead of parsing the variable as a template argument like I was trying to: `self._template_args['all_transactions'] = #current_shop_object#.transactions.order_by(Transaction.timestamp.desc())`,

{{ model.transactions.all() }} achieves the result I was aiming for.